# PHP commands showing on page

Tags: php

Unfortunately all of my PHP commands showing on page as HTML, I don't know why. I had to use it before without errors though. What is my mistake here?
..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Add items system</title>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 if(isset($_POST['yes']))
 {
  file_put_contents('ak47content.html', '<li class="li1"><img src="images/'.$_POST["image"].'.png"><span><b>Available:</b> <br>'.$_POST['available'].'<br><br><img src="images/hiks.png"><br>&nbsp;</span></li>' . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
 }
 
else
{
 if(isset($_POST['no']))
 {
  file_put_contents('ak47content.html', '<li class="li1"><img src="images/'.$_POST['image'].'.png"><span><b>Available:</b> <br>'.$_POST['available'].'<br><br><img src="images/hiks.png"><br>&nbsp;</span></li>' . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
 }
  
 else
 {
  echo "Please specify if it's available or not!";
 }
}
 
 
 
 
}

?>
</head>
<body>

<form action="add.php" method="post" name="all">
<b>Available:</b> <input type="radio" name="yes" value="male">Yes <input type="radio" name="no" value="male">No <br>

<b>If NOT available, so when:</b>
 <select name="available">
   <option>Soon</option>
   <option>Next week</option>
   <option>Next month</option>
   <option>Next year</option>
  </select><br>
  
  
<b>Exteriors:</b>  <select name="exterior">
   <option>Battle-Scarred</option>
   <option>Factory New</option>
   <option>Minimal Wear, Battle-Scarred</option>
   <option>Field-Tested, Battle-Scarred</option>
   <option>Factory New, Field-Tested</option>
   </select><br>
<b>Image name:</b> <input type="text" name="image"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stupid question but does this file has .php extension?

Comment: Are you serving the page from the web server? What server are you using?

Comment: Did you checked file handling configuration of web server for this type of files (`.php`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not interpreted as PHP, check if PHP is up and running!**
- check the file extension
- make sure that php is integrated correctly with your server
- try to reinstall xampp